# PyCharmのショートカットキー`Ctrl+Shift+引用符`は、どのキーを押せばよいですか？

Tags: python, intellij-idea

## 環境

#### PyCharm

PyCharm 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-181.5087.37, built on May 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

#### PC

ThinkPad T460s

## やりたいこと

ツールウィンドウを、ショートカットキーで最大化したいです。
PyCharmのキーマップを確認すると、ショートカットキーは、`Ctrl+Shift+引用符`でした。
（Maximize Tool Window）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

`引用符`キーは、どのキーを押せばよいのでしょうか？
二重引用符、一重引用符、バッククォートを試しましたが、ツールウィンドウは最大化されませんでした。

Comment: 英語キーボード向けのショートカットだと思うので、自分でショートカットをカスタマイズする必要があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tanalab2 さんが仰るとおり、英語キーボード用の設定なので、キーマップを変えないと駄目みたいです。引用符は`""`（ダブルクォーテーション）を意味しているようですが、ダブルクォーテーションは日本語キーボードでは<kbd>Shift</kbd>キーを押す必要があるので、キーがかぶってしまいますね。

設定は、File > Settings > Keymap で検索ウインドウに「max」と入力すると、「ツールウィンドウは最大化」が出てくるので、適当なショートカットに変えて下さい。